# Swift UITableView not showing all result

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I have UITableView hook up to an array. 
var shoppingList: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"]
However, when I run the app in the simulator, it doesn't allow me to scroll to the end. Why is that? I can only scroll to the letter "I" and see half of the "J", but I can't scroll down further. In the func tableView, it shows the correct array size, so I know the items are all there, but can't scroll to the the end. Below is the screen shot. thank you.
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJbxE.png)
[screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wbh1.png)

here's the code

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var shoppingList: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("test")
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print(shoppingList.count)
        return shoppingList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel!.text = shoppingList[indexPath.row]
        // Configure the cell...
        print("here")
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: How can we help you if you don't post your code?

Comment: thanks, I just posted the code.

Comment: where do you set the size of the tableView? If the tableview is longer than the screen you won't see the last few elements

Comment: Why you tag objective-c in Swift question?

Comment: how do I set the size of the tableView? I put it within the viewcontrol. I uploaded another screen shot of the the layout. Sorry, because I thought this more of a UI question rather the code, and since object c use the same UI, I might as well tag it.

Comment: Assuming by her credentials, she's new. But Evgeniy is right.

Answer (score 1):

Julia, It seems that the table view is longer than the screen itself. If you go into your story board and shorten the length of your tableview, you will be able to see the rest as along as it's the same or shorter size of the screen.

You can add constraints that will automatically snap to the fit what ever size of screen.

If you want to do it by code, try this in your viewDidLoad()

```
    tableView.frame.size = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to drag the tableview, how do I set the size of it? How to add constraints that will automatically snap to fit because eventually I need to populate it with dynamic data. Also, I get an error when tried to size it in the code, it says "cannot assign a   type 'CGRect' to a vlue of type CGSize

Comment: In this case, It's more difficult to type this out. YouTube, auto constraights. It's super simple to show rather than type.